# Comma placement with essential and non-essential clause

Tags: commas

I was given two sentences and the task is to correct them or leave them the way they are. I've googled many examples and explanations of comma placement, but I'm still unsure whether my solutions are correct:

1. GIVEN:

- My parents used to tell me that if I crossed my eyes they would stay that way forever.

MY SOLUTION:

- My parents used to tell me that if I crossed my eyes, they would stay that way forever.

2. GIVEN:

- Now that I’m older and wiser I know that they were just making fun of me.

MY SOLUTION:

- Now that I’m older and wiser, I know that they were only making fun of me.

My question is: In the first given sentence, do I need the comma or not? Regarding the stuff I've read, I think I might not need that comma after all. In the second given sentence, I also placed the comma and I am more confident about that decision.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I'm sure this has been covered here before, but if I can't find it, why should you be able to? (1) I'd use no commas here (I'd read it without any pause), but if commas are liked, I feel you'd be better with one either side of _if I crossed my eyes_. //  Most style guides like a comma to offset an introductory element (here a temporal adverbial, or one explaining reason) of five words or over (and many others). As in your answer.  But there is a move towards more minimal punctuation, and, free of editorial / professorial constraints, I'd omit it. But it's certainly at least permissible.

Comment: I agree with Edwin. No commas at all is the best way to go in both cases.